# Wordpress admin links

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm in a situation in which I have WP installed and running on the root.
I have a custom created folder, lets call it "my_folder".

`"my_folder"` is in the root too, and there are files which are included for my themes functions, and that pages content is displayed on the admin dashboard.
The problem comes when i visit this page, the admin menu is still there, but it is not linking like:

```
mysite.com/wp-admin/etc..
```

it links like:

```
mysite.com/my_folder/etc..
```

Which is incorrect..

I guess this is because admin menu takes relative url (from the current directory which we are in). But how I can fix that?

Comment: Could you please post the content of your admin menu file here?

Comment: Not sure which file you mean, there are a lot of menu files... also, they are not touched by me, all are default

Comment: Sorry.. I did not get you.Can you tell me exactly what are you looking for ?

Comment: I have a custom php page, located under: my_folder/costom_page.php.
This page has the wp-admin menu on the left, but the links are not pointing to: site.com/wp-admin/... , they are pointing to: site.com/my_folder/...

Comment: Sure, there are some files. I suppose there is some variable in there which points to the current directory and not the root directory of the installation. But to confirm this, you have to provide the content of the the menu file. Which files do you have? Why did you move the theme to another folder?